# A question about the definition of$\sigma|\approx p$ for a sequence $\sigma$ and a proposition $p$

Tags: logic

I am reading an article which talks about temporal semantics.

For a sequence $$\sigma=s_{0},s_{1},\ldots$$ and a proposition
$p$ the article defines a few things such as $$\sigma|\approx W_{1}\vee W_{2}\text{ iff }\sigma|\approx W_{1}\text{ or }\sigma|\approx W_{2}$$ and
$$\sigma|\approx\sim W\text{ iff }\sigma|\not\approx W$$

However, there is one definition that I don't understand $$\sigma|\approx p\text{ iff }s_{0}|\approx p$$

What is the reasoning behind looking only at the first element in
the sequence ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly: What does it take for $p$ *to be true now* (according to a model $\sigma$, where $\sigma$ represents a world-history)? $p$ needs to be true with respect to the world-in-the-model which represents the present, i.e. the world indexed $s_0$ in the possible from-now-on history $s_0, s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots$. Thus $\sigma$ makes $p$ currently true iff $p \in s_0$ (or $p$ is true at $s_0$, i.e. $p$ is true at at the element of $\sigma$ which represents the present).

Comment: Thanks Peter! [sapce filler]